# Is locking a document with a GET request evil

Tags: http, web

I'm trying to implement pessimistic concurrency for a web application and I am having some issues on how I should proceed to lock my document. At the moment, I'm being told that to lock a document, it should be a POST action instead of locking the document from a GET action.

I understand that a GET method should be idempotent and only return the document without any side effect. I also read about conditionnal and partial GET but that does not seems to fix my issue since none of the header fields seems usable for pessimistic concurrency.

On the other end, a POST method should send a document that the server should use to replace an existing one or to create it from if that document did not exist on the server. I find it perplexing to obtain my document on a POST action.

I am quite confused about this. I honestly do not know how to proceed. Is locking the document for other readers from a GET request considered a side effect.

EDIT:
I know I will get lynched for that but I have any other idea even tho it feels wrong.

First step is checking with a get request if the document is locked. Depending on the answer of that request, three things can happen.

If it's unlocked, I submit a form to execute a POST action to get the document. Why? So that someone that hit refresh doesn't loose control of the document and is not told that the document is locked since there is a hidden token that verify if it's the same lock.

If it's locked by another user, I'm telling the user that it can't access it right now.

If the user tried to opened a second time the same document, I need to ask him if he want to take control of said document in that particular tab. If he does, I get the document and create a new lock to invalidate the previous one.

Comment: Why do you need to lock the resource from other readers? In most of situations, you would use [_conditional requests_](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7232) for optimistic locking without locking clients that want to request a representation of the resource.

Comment: "On the other end, a POST method should send a document that the server should use to replace an existing one or to create it from if that document did not exist on the server. I find it perplexing to obtain my document on a POST action." - says who?

Comment: I read about the GET and POST action here: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html

Comment: I need to lock the document so that only one user at a time can work with the document.

Comment: Is it not possible to use both a GET and POST method in your app (or even PUT or PATCH)? For example you could GET the document (and return it's lock status simultaneously), POST a request for the lock given the user's id, and then PATCH changes iff the user has the lock. Ultimately the HTTP specifications are basically guidelines so don't put too much thought into the wording. However, the caveat is that some browsers/servers will cache GET requests and will never even bother performing your intended side-effects, but I've never personally seen this come up as an issue.

Comment: **Don't use the old RFC 2616 anymore.** It was obsoleted by the RFCs 7230-35, which together define the protocol HTTP/1.1. By the way, [Julian Reschke](https://stackoverflow.com/u/50543), who [commented above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50857866/is-locking-a-document-with-a-get-request-evil#comment88718718_50857866), is one of the authors of those documents.

Comment: I added some information about how I'm being told to proceed. I hope this can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is locking the document for other readers from a `GET` request considered a side effect?

`GET` is a *safe method* and shouldn't be used for locking a resource. From the [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231):

> [**4.2.1.  Safe Methods**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.1)
>
> Request methods are considered "safe" if their defined semantics are
> essentially read-only; i.e., the client does not request, and does
> not expect, any state change on the origin server as a result of
> applying a safe method to a target resource. [...]

---

*Pessimitic locking* could be handled with different requests for retrieving a representation of the resource and creating a lock. See the examples below.

Request a representation of the resource:

```
GET /document/1 HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
```

Create a lock:

```
POST /document/1/lock HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
```

Modify the resource:

```
PUT /document/1 HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Content-Type: text/plain

This is the new content of the document.
```

Release the lock:

```
DELETE /document/1/lock HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
```

Attempts to modify or retrieve a representation of a locked resource could return [`409`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.8) indicating that the request could not be completed due to a conflict with the current state of the target resource. The server also should generate a payload that includes enough information for a user to recognize the source of the conflict.

---

If *optimistic locking* suits you, consider [*conditional requests*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232):

> Conditional requests are HTTP requests that include one or
> more header fields indicating a precondition to be tested before
> applying the method semantics to the target resource. [...]
>
> Conditional `GET` requests are the most efficient mechanism for HTTP
> cache updates. Conditionals can also be applied to
> state-changing methods, such as `PUT` and `DELETE`, to prevent the "lost
> update" problem: one client accidentally overwriting the work of
> another client that has been acting in parallel. [...]

Check the [RFC 7232](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232) for further details.

Comment: But I want a pessimistic lock.

Comment: @StéphanePelletier-Lamothe I've added more details to my answer.